# How can I install a specific version of Ionic 4.13.11?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to upgrade an ionic/angular app from Ionic 3 to 4, my current version is 3.9.0 and the traditional `npm install ionic@4.13.11` does not work.

I tried many tutorials but seems Ionic has changed his way of installation, I tried to install ionic/angular@4.13.11 but if I install the latest version of `npm install -g ionic` it conflicts.

I tried to install only @ionic/angular@4.13.11 with my current global ionic, but it conflicts even with node version, my app runs in `node v14.17.0`, I updated the node to many versions like v14.20, v16.10 and the latest but also conflicts.

Comment: new command is: `npm install -g @ionic/cli`. Please refer to documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Yeah, i saw that, but the @ionic/cli start in 6.0..0 version accoding to npmjs.com, the ionic packages are confusing, i saw in a tuto that the ionic 4 is the package @ionic/angular and not the ionic-angular which is the 3 version. But i still cant solve the problem to install ionic 4 with the correct packages

Comment: ionic is now in V7, why do you want to use v4? upgrade to latest.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib because the docs said its better to do 3 to 4, 4 to 5, 5 to 6 and 6 to 7.
I will upgrade to 7 but i need to do slowly to not compromise the application